# Multiple instances of QWebView (qt jambi)

Tags: multithreading, qwebview

Good day,
How I can use QWebView with method load() in threads?
I have create QWebView in main(!) thread, but I can't use load() with QWebView (used signals/slots from other threads to do it):

QWebView wv = new QWebView(); //ok 
QUrl url = new QUrl("http://somesite.com/"); //ok 
wv.load(url); //ERROR: QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.

In c++ it work. Please, help me!

p.s. sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but for anyone else interested, the problem is creating children on a different thread. To marshal back to the owning thread, do something like the following:

```
public void loadURL(String url) {  
    QApplication.invokeLater(new LoadURL(url));
}

private class LoadURL implements Runnable {
    private String url;
    public LoadURL(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public void run() {
        QNetworkRequest nreq = new QNetworkRequest(new QUrl(this.url));
        load(nreq);
    }
}
```